# Capistrano not creating symlinks

Tags: git, deployment, capistrano

I have created a cap file to deploy a site, it all works except the symlinks are not being created, I have recently formatted my computer so maybe the syntax has changed, I am not sure.

```
namespace :myproject do
    task :symlink, :roles => :app do
       run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/site_files/apache_password/.htaccess #{release_path}/src/public"
       run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/site_files/tmp #{release_path}/src/private/app/tmp"
       run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/site_files/media #{release_path}/src/public/media"
       run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/site_files/Config/database.php #{release_path}/src/private/app/Config/database.php"
       run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/site_files/Config/core.php #{release_path}/src/private/app/Config/core.php"
    end
end

after "deploy:symlink", "myproject:symlink"
```

Terminal Response:

```
* 2012-10-29 11:27:10 executing `deploy:symlink'
* executing "rm -f /var/www/SITENAME/current && ln -s /var/www/SITENAME/releases/20121029112219 /var/www/SITENAME/current"
    servers: ["SERVERNAME"]
        [SERVERNAME] executing command 
    command finished in 74ms
```

Comment: Is the task being run - do you see it in your capistrano output? What does `cap myproject:symlink` output?

Comment: Nick,
I get the following in terminal:
    * 2012-10-29 11:27:10 executing `deploy:symlink'
* executing "rm -f /var/www/SITENAME/current && ln -s /var/www/SITENAME/releases/20121029112219 /var/www/SITENAME/current"
 servers: ["SERVERNAME"]
     [SERVERNAME] executing command 
        command finished in 74ms

Comment: You've edited in the output for `deploy:symlink` but what does `cap myproject:symlink` output i.e. your custom task?